# How to idiomatically tell someone to become more humble?

Tags: idiom-request

Suppose someone is too full of himself because he thinks he is so good, if I wanted to advise him to act more humbly, what should I say? I'm familiar with *turn your nose up at someone or something*, and I'm not sure the opposite, lower your nose or turn your nose down, would be correct English, as in:

> Hey! I've had it with you! You ***need to lower your nose a bit***.

Comment: Why is "Don't be so full of yourself." (the negation of the expression you initially use) insufficient for this purpose?

Comment: Because in my first language, the equivalent of _need_ is usually used. So I was looking for an expression that can be preceded by *you need to*, *you should* or the likes.

Answer (score 2):

Its not very idiomatic to tell people to be humble.  Humble in not a big part of the culture of English speaking countries.  So there isn't a rich source of idioms or metaphors to use.

Instead just be literal:

> I've had it with you.  You're too proud.

There are some expressions meaning "proud" in a negative way:

> You're too full of yourself. You're conceited and arrogant.

Answer (score 2):

> be up yourself
>
> ***uk*** slang ​ to think that you are better and more important than other people:
>
> She's so up herself since she landed this new job, it's unbearable.
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-up-yourself

British slang - I've had enough of you. You're so up yourself.

Note that this is very confrontational, it literally means, "You are up your own backside"

Comment: Why being up your own buttocks is taken to mean conceited?Aren't we all literally up our own buttocks? The head is up and the buttock is down. :)

Comment: Slang doesn't have to make sense ;-) Have a look at this - https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=up%20themselves

Answer (score 1):

You could tell him to step down from his pedestal.

> It was the only honest thing to do, but very hard for the poor fellow to crush his little vanities, renounce the delights so dear to the young, own his folly, and step down from his pedestal to be pitied, laughed at, and forgotten.

[Jo's Boys](https://books.google.com/books?id=ATCOPbGkyPYC&pg=PT125&dq=%22step%20down%20from%20his%20pedestal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqy5uLs73fAhUJZd8KHdNoDs0Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22step%20down%20from%20his%20pedestal%22&f=false) by Louisa May Alcott